# My Flexbox keeps shrinking when I link the full div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm creating buttons and to center them perfectly in the middle I'm using a flexbox wrapper around my divs that are floating left once I link the full div the "Five Columns" shrink below is a sample of the code. What I'm trying to accomplish is having 5 columns in each column will be a icon aligned right of the text.

```css
.FlexBox {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.FiveColumns {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
.GreyBorder {
  border: 2px solid #B2B2B2;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="FullWidth FlexBox">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="AirFare_HyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="">
      <div class="FiveColumns GreyBorder">
        <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://mktcdn.500px.org/assets/icons/lightbox_placeholder_icon@2x-a5b4509ac42a996d07b9f32379f1eae19310a57d38e5914c59230bfa36815c9a.png" />
        <h6 class="Blue Bold NoMargin">
                                        AIRFARE
                                        <p class="Italic">product</p>
                                    </h6>
      </div>
    </asp:HyperLink>

    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="">
      <div class="FiveColumns GreyBorder">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://mktcdn.500px.org/assets/icons/lightbox_placeholder_icon@2x-a5b4509ac42a996d07b9f32379f1eae19310a57d38e5914c59230bfa36815c9a.png" />
        <h6 class="Blue Bold NoMargin">
                                        CRUISE
                                        <p class="Italic">product</p>
                                    </h6>
      </div>
    </asp:HyperLink>

    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="">
      <div class="FiveColumns GreyBorder">
        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://mktcdn.500px.org/assets/icons/lightbox_placeholder_icon@2x-a5b4509ac42a996d07b9f32379f1eae19310a57d38e5914c59230bfa36815c9a.png" />
        <h6 class="Blue Bold NoMargin">
                                        VACATION
                                        <p class="Italic">product</p>
                                    </h6>
      </div>
    </asp:HyperLink>

    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" NavigateUrl="">
      <div class="FiveColumns GreyBorder ">
        <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://mktcdn.500px.org/assets/icons/lightbox_placeholder_icon@2x-a5b4509ac42a996d07b9f32379f1eae19310a57d38e5914c59230bfa36815c9a.png" />
        <h6 class="Blue Bold NoMargin">
                                        REBATE
                                        <p class="Italic">product</p>
                                    </h6>

      </div>
    </asp:HyperLink>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/4apL0meg/2/

Comment: that's exactly how I wanted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.FiveColumns {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

Try this:

```
.FiveColumns {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Note that flex containers ignore the `float` property on child elements:

> [**3. Flex Containers: the `flex` and `inline-flex` display
>   values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)
>
> - `float` and `clear` have no effect on a flex item, and do not take it out-of-flow.

Comment: Now my problem is that I can't drop text below the "heading" text with it displaying flex any work arounds for that? is displays right next to the heading vs under it

Comment: The default `flex-direction` is `row`. This means flex items line up in horizontally. Make any parent a flex container and apply `flex-direction: column`, and the flex items will stack vertically. https://jsfiddle.net/4apL0meg/5/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `width: 20%` as the columns are already in a flexbox.
This is your code with the modification at `.FiveColumns`:

```css
.FlexBox {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.FiveColumns {
  float: left;
}
.GreyBorder {
  border: 2px solid #B2B2B2;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="FullWidth FlexBox">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="AirFare_HyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="">
      <div class="FiveColumns GreyBorder">
        <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://mktcdn.500px.org/assets/icons/lightbox_placeholder_icon@2x-a5b4509ac42a996d07b9f32379f1eae19310a57d38e5914c59230bfa36815c9a.png" />
        <h6 class="Blue Bold NoMargin">
                                        AIRFARE
                                        <p class="Italic">product</p>
                                    </h6>
      </div>
    </asp:HyperLink>

    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="">
      <div class="FiveColumns GreyBorder">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://mktcdn.500px.org/assets/icons/lightbox_placeholder_icon@2x-a5b4509ac42a996d07b9f32379f1eae19310a57d38e5914c59230bfa36815c9a.png" />
        <h6 class="Blue Bold NoMargin">
                                        CRUISE
                                        <p class="Italic">product</p>
                                    </h6>
      </div>
    </asp:HyperLink>

    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="">
      <div class="FiveColumns GreyBorder">
        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://mktcdn.500px.org/assets/icons/lightbox_placeholder_icon@2x-a5b4509ac42a996d07b9f32379f1eae19310a57d38e5914c59230bfa36815c9a.png" />
        <h6 class="Blue Bold NoMargin">
                                        VACATION
                                        <p class="Italic">product</p>
                                    </h6>
      </div>
    </asp:HyperLink>

    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" NavigateUrl="">
      <div class="FiveColumns GreyBorder ">
        <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://mktcdn.500px.org/assets/icons/lightbox_placeholder_icon@2x-a5b4509ac42a996d07b9f32379f1eae19310a57d38e5914c59230bfa36815c9a.png" />
        <h6 class="Blue Bold NoMargin">
                                        REBATE
                                        <p class="Italic">product</p>
                                    </h6>

      </div>
    </asp:HyperLink>
  </div>
</section>
```

Where is the `.FullWidth` class?

Comment: .Fullwidth is just 100%